# When using the method of characteristics, do we ever need the equation for the gradient?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a question about the method of characteristics (as defined in the *PDE* book by Evans).

He summarizes the characteristic equations as (see eq. 11 on p. 98):
(using $p=Du,z=u$ and the variable $x$)

a) $\dot{p} = -D_xF- D_zF p$

b) $\dot{z} = \langle D_pF, p \rangle$

c) $\dot{x} = D_pF$

to the PDE $F(Du,u,x) = 0$ and $u=g$ on some boundary.

Now at the end of p. 99 he says " We will see later that the equation for $p$ is not needed."

Then on p.101 he solves a PDE with fully non-linear $F$, but makes use of the equation for $p$.

On p. 109 he says then: " Note carefully that although we have utilized the full characteristic equations in the proof of Theorem 2 ( local existence of solutions using the method of charactersitcs), one we know the solution exists, we can use the reduced equations (only b)+c)) (which do not involve $p$) to compute the solution.

I am confused now: Does this mean that if I want to solve a PDE using the method of characteristics I never have to use equation a) or does this only apply to the quasi-linear or even only linear cases?

If anything is unclear about my question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using the first edition of the book. This point is made clear in the second edition: $p$ can be eliminated from the characteristic equations for linear and quasilinear PDE of first order, but not in general (i.e., for fully nonlinear PDE of first order, like $u_{x_1}u_{x_2}=u$).